# azure-cli | mkdir: cannot create directory | Permission denied

Tags: azure, hyperledger-fabric, azure-cli, azure-aks

I am trying to setup hyperledger fabric on Azure Kubernetes Service. For that I am following [this article](https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2020/02/17/hyperledger-fabric-tutorial-on-azure/comment-page-1/?unapproved=32612&moderation-hash=113df8deec7aa5be1fafccc26e3b0052#comment-32612). I need to create directory like `mkdir /usr/local/hyperledger` as per the instruction in the article. But I am getting the following error.

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hyperledger’: Permission denied
```

Help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you are running the command as a non-root user. To gain root permissions for a single command, invoke the command with `sudo`, e.g. `sudo mkdir /usr/local/hyperledger`. I don't think this is the solution to your problem though.

You shouldn't need to run these steps manually if your target environment is AKS. You should be preparing a docker image to run in your cluster, rather than using shell commands to modify a VM/container.

The author of the article has provided a Dockerfile which you can use to build a docker image, or you can retrieve the [pre-built image from Docker Hub: `tsmatz/hyperledger-dev`](https://hub.docker.com/r/tsmatz/hyperledger-dev).